# Unable to set environment variable for current session in terraform

Tags: terraform

I have a terraform local-exec through which I execute

```bash
export ABC=value
```

The subsequent module has a local-exec internally and reading the value from environment

```bash
echo $ABC > file.txt
```

When i execute is an empty `file.txt` is created
The second local-exec which resides in the module is not able to fetch from the apply session in terraform

```
resource "null_resource" "export_environment_variable" {
  triggers = {
    always = timestamp()
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "export ABC=value"
  }
}

module "module_internal {
   src = "./internal-module"
   depends_on = [null_resource.export_environment_variable]
}
```

/internal-module

```
resource "null_resource" "write-to-file" {
  triggers = {
    always = timestamp()
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo $ABC > file.txt"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share the entire code block.

Comment: Why not do both in the same `null_resource`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `local-exec` in the way you've shown, Terraform starts your shell as a child process and asks the shell to evaluate the script. After the script is evaluated, the shell process ends and so any in-memory state such as shell variables are lost.

In your example you have two separate `local-exec` provisioners and therefore two separate *end entirely independent* shell sessions. What you have done here is similar to what might happen if you followed the following steps:

1. Open a terminal in a window on your computer.
2. In that terminal, run `export ABC=value`.
3. Open another separate terminal in a separate window on your computer.
4. In that terminal, run `echo $ABC`.

Just as with the two separate `local-exec` provisioners in Terraform, these two terminals each have their own separate instance of your shell running and so do not share in-memory state such as shell variables.

If you want to set a shell variable and then use it later you will need to do both in the same shell process, which means doing both in the same `local-exec` provisioner:

```
resource "null_resource" "export_environment_variable" {
  triggers = {
    always = timestamp()
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<-EOT
      export ABC=value
      echo $ABC > file.txt
    EOT
  }
}
```

---

Note that [provisioners are a last resort](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/provisioners/syntax#provisioners-are-a-last-resort) and there is probably a better way to achieve this goal that doesn't involve using `local-exec` at all. I've focused on `local-exec` here because that's what you asked the question about, but this is perhaps an example of [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) and if you're interested in exploring alternative solutions I would suggest starting a new question that describes the real problem you have without assuming that provisioners are involved in the solution.